# Does Apple Developer account have a limit on how many accounts it can mange?

Tags: ios, app-store, apple-developer

We develop whitelabelled apps. To comply with apple guidelines, we make our customers create their own apple developer account and then they invite our account to manage theirs (bcs according to apple guidelines it is the content owner that needs to submit the app to the appstore, not the developer of whitelabelled solution).

So far I manage cca 60 accounts (all of them invited one account that I am the Account Holder for). Everything worked fine (other than it makes automation little bit more challenging), until I wasnt able to find one of the teams in the teams list on apple dev portal.

So on appstore connect I saw that I am member of this team with access to dev resources (apple dev portal). But in the apple dev portal this team was not in the list of teams to choose from.

I have left some other teams then, and this team suddenly appeared in the list of teams to choose from.

Conclusion I made is that there is a limit on how many accounts you can manage from one account. I have asked apple if that is true, but it has been several days and no answer (I posted a bug report through their bug reporter, and I also sent this question to them through web form on their site).

Has anyone encountered this limit? if so, do you have information on how big this limit is? And how did you solve this whole situation? Did you create a new apple id that your customers invite to manage their accounts now?

I am kinda lost now, and apple being silent about this (and the fact that I have not found this documented anywhere) isnt really helping.

Comment: Update April 2019: Just an observation: One Apple ID is now member of 80+ teams. Not sure if they changed anything or it depends on when the Apple ID was created.

Comment: And do you mean teams in appstore connect, or developer portal? 

Bcs in my experience this limit was only on dev portal, on appstore connect this issue did not manifest for me

Comment: As both team are now linked (unification of the teams earlier this year), I have access to both for more than 60+ teams

Comment: @Max what is your experience now? Anyone reached 100+?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a team limit of 60 teams per Apple ID. You will need to create a new Apple ID and get your invites on that. (Have currently ~ 5 examples of that, so it's definitely not a bug) And yes, there is no official documentation of that.

Answer (score 2):

We hit the limit the other day. We removed ourselves from some older accounts so I can’t confirm the exact figure, but we have a user that is currently a member of 495 teams, so I expect the limit as of March 2022 is 500 teams.

Beware that App Store Connect is not efficient *at all* when it comes to this volume, so you’ll be waiting more than ten seconds for some API calls to be made to the backend when you load a page (10s is the time-to-first-byte and the total size of the response is about 100KB, so it’s a backend delay rather than the connection).

I would recommend sharing across multiple accounts long before you hit the limit.

Comment: is there any official document?

Comment: Not as far as I am aware, @BhargavB.Bajani